# How to export variables from Bash into tcl?

Tags: bash, variables, export, tcl

I have variables A, B, and C.

I have written

```
export A=$A
export B=$B
export C=$C
```

Not sure how to carry the variables over into a tcl script. What I currently have written in the tcl script is

```
puts "$A == $::env(A)"
puts "$B == $::env(B)"
puts "$C == $::env(C)"
```

But that doesn't work. I have tried with and without the first $.

Comment: Note on bash. You do not need to assign `A` to `A` on export. If the variable is already defined, just `export A` exports it into the environment. As for Tcl, I do not do Tcl, but `puts "A == $::env(A)"` seems to have worked for me.

Comment: They can all be exported in one line: `export A B C`.  Then they will be in the child process's environment block regardless of the language.

Answer (score 2):

Either way is meant to work:

```
$ export A="a"
$ echo "puts $::env(A)" | tclsh
a
```

or

```
$ export B="b"; echo "puts $::env(B)" | tclsh
b
```

or

```
$ echo "puts $::env(C)" | C="c" tclsh
c
```

Comment: thx @glennjackman, the example was meant to come out different, as Donal has posted in the meantime ...

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways. Either you export the variable (there are a few ways to do that) or you assign it as part of the call to `tclsh`. Using `export`:

```
export B="b"
echo 'puts "the B environment variable is $::env(B)"' | tclsh
```

```
B="b"
export B
echo 'puts "the B environment variable is $::env(B)"' | tclsh
```

Assigning as part of the call (NB: *no semicolons* and the variable assignment is close to the actual call to `tclsh`):

```
echo 'puts "the B environment variable is $::env(B)"' | B="b" tclsh
```

For anything complex or large, try to avoid passing it via environment variables (or command line arguments). Using files works better in those cases. **For anything *secret*, DO NOT use *either* command line arguments or environment variables** as neither is a secure communication mechanism, but files (with appropriate permissions, including on the containing directory) are sufficiently secure.